# Cannot find module '../built/cli.js' when running Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, protractor

Because of the [present in Protractor 3.3.0 issue with `getMultiCapabilities`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3191), we have to install Protractor directly from github since the master branch contains [the fix](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3195) which is scheduled for Protractor 3.4.

In `package.json` we've added the following:

```
"dependencies": {
  "protractor": "git+https://github.com/angular/protractor.git"
},
```

And, now, we are getting the following error when trying to run `protractor`:

```
> protractor conf.js

module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../built/cli.js'
```

Is it something we are doing wrong, or `Protractor` development version cannot be installed and used this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i see, one step is missing. Protractor has prepublish step in package.json , you can call it manually, or try to do the same as this step do:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../built/cli.js'
```

What i see in https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L76:

```
gulp.task('prepublish', function(done) {
  runSequence(['typings', 'jshint', 'format'], 'tsc', 'tsc:globals', 'types',
    'ambient', 'built:copy', done);
});

gulp.task('built:copy', function() {
  return gulp.src(['lib/**/*','!lib/**/*.ts'])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('built/'));
});
```

I think you just need to do postinstall task, that will copy that files to destination.

Answer (score 2):

There are differents between package downloading on `npm` and fetching directly on git repo.

And the main point prevent your protractor to run is:

```
//protractor from git repo, inside ./bin/protractor
require('../built/cli.js');

//protractor from npm, inside ./bin/protractor
require('../lib/cli.js');
```

So basically you need to go to `protractor` local folder then execute gulp task `'prepublish'` to setup the environment for `protractor`. It will be something like this:

```
// from your project directory
cd node_modules/protractor
// install base dependencies for protractor
npm install
// setup environment by publishing
gulp prepublish
```

Comment: It should be something like that - currently still figuring out the exact steps to make the protractor command work in this case. I'll let you know if I find the sequence of commands to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe before answer the question I've tried to clone protractor from git repo. But just now I tried to install it through `npm` command. And seem like **important folders being missed** when fetching the package with `npm` & `github`. Could you please check if inside `node_modules/protractor` you have folders like: `lib`, `script`...? because in my case these folder are not fetched with installation through `npm`

Comment: Mhm, that is yet another strange thing about it, it looks very much cut down when installed from github, directories are missing. Thanks.